# How to add some labels on a photo and show a text when i touch each label

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, google-maps-markers

I'm developing android app that handle some processes on photos
like zoom, blur, crop and so on.

for now, i have a one photo
and i just wanna put some labels on this photo on a specific places
And when i touch the label it shows me a text

How to do it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create 2 textViews one for label and another for your Text
- set the second textView visibility to gone
- setOnClickListener on the first TextView :- set visibility for the second text to Visible